# Network Error when I try to run React web on AWS

Tags: node.js, reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Sorry maybe it is a dump question but I could not go further.

I got a website which already built with `ReactJS` and working on `AWS Ec2`

When I run on `localhost`

- First; in terminal which in file directory run `node server.js`
- `yarn start`

then I can see the `localhost:3000` then when I make any changing just send with SSH and run server with `PM2` which `pm2 restart server`

My question is I want to create a second AWS EC2 instance and run the code there as well when I change `config.json` which domain is store there I can see a `NETWORK ERROR`

I created a ec2 instance copied all my files there and I installed NodeJS npm and pm2 but I could not managed see my website on `localhost:3000()`

What Do I have to do?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the EC2 public address/IP not localhost

Comment: Ok might you missed something. My first Ec2 instance I am not typing adress because store in config.js. For your point it is not working too